# How to create different kinds of Mac Windows using File menu commands?

Tags: macos, swiftui, window

I'm writing a cross-platform SwiftUI-based app that lets users create different types of "screens". It's a word puzzle helper. You can create screens to help solve Wordle puzzles, Anagrams, or crossword puzzle like puzzles.

Right now it uses a TabView on each window, and users can switch between tabs. However, that causes some problems, and I've concluded that for the macOS version of the app I instead want to let the user create new Wordle, Anagram, or Crossword windows.

Adding a `WindowGroup` to my app lets me create windows of that type from the `File` menu's "New Window" command.

The `Window(_:, id:)` struct defines a single instance of a window. If you use the `openWindow(id:)` action, it opens a "singleton" of that window. Users can't open multiple instances of a `Window()` with a specific ID.

How would I go about adding "New Wordle Window", "New Anagrams Window" and "New Crosswords Window" menu items to the file menu, so that each time the user selects that menu item it creates a new instance of that type of Window?

(For the iOS version of my app I may keep the tabbed approach where users can switch between single instances of a Wordle, Anagram, and Crosswords screen via a TabView.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add menu items to the main menu using [`commands`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scene/commands(content:)). This takes a `CommandsBuilder` closure that builds a `Commands`.

Using a `CommandGroup`, you can replace the "New Window" menu item added by `WindowGroup`s by default.

```
struct OpenWindowCommands: Commands {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var open
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(replacing: .newItem) { // .newItem is where the New Window/Open menu items are placed
            Button("New Anagrams Window") {
                open(id: "Anagrams")
            }
            Button("New Wordle Window") {
                open(id: "Wordle")
            }
            Button("New Crosswords Window") {
                open(id: "Crosswords")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can have 3 `WindowGroup`s:

```
WindowGroup(id: "Anagrams") {
    Text("Anagrams Window")
}.commands { OpenWindowCommands() }

WindowGroup(id: "Wordle") {
    Text("Wordle")
}
.commands { OpenWindowCommands() }

WindowGroup(id: "Crosswords") {
    Text("Crosswords")
}
.commands { OpenWindowCommands() }
```

Output:

[image]

---

If anagrams, wordles, and crosswords are represented by custom structs you wrote, you can use the `[init(for:content:)`][3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/windowgroup/init(for:content:)) initialiser instead.

```
/*
Assuming you have

struct Anagram: Codable, Hashable {
    ...
}
*/

WindowGroup(for: Anagram.self) { $anagram in
    // ...
}

// the "open" calls should be changed to use the value: parameter
open(value: Anagram(...))
```

If the anagrams, wordles and crosswords are files (documents) that your app supports opening and writing, consider using a [`DocumentGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/documentgroup) instead.

Comment: Cool. That's a step in the right direction. It introduces a new problem however. Each of my types of windows has an ObservableObject to hold state data and provide functions that mutate that state. With the default single WindowGroup and 3 tabs, each window gets a unique ObservableObject as desired. When I create a separate WindowGroup for each type of window, each type ends up sharing a single ObservableObject so they no longer have unique state. Why is that, and how do I fix it?

Comment: @DuncanC You would need to show a [mcve], probably in a new question. How are you creating the `ObservableObject`s? If you are just doing `.environmentObject(SomeObservableObject())`, then everything will share the same observable object. If you use `@StateObject` in the views of each window, I don't think that should happen.

Comment: I was declaring my object as an `@ObservedObject`. Simply switching to `@StateObject` seems to fix it. Thanks for that!